# Looking for good reference book in molecular biology

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, book-recommendation

I am starting to work in molecular biology/ molecular genetic and I am looking for a really good book containing the main concepts and mostly the more recent techniques.

I would be interested in a book that has also protocol examples and examples on how to apply the different techniques.
My focus is on bacteria and fungi.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Usually questions asking for book recommendations are considered 'opinion-based' if specific details are not mentioned.

Comment: *Molecular biology* by R.F. Weaver is an excellent book. Concepts are very much clear-cut.

Answer (score 4):

These always have a place at my library

HF Lodish, Berk, Arnold, and S. Lawrence Zipursky. Molecular cell biology. Vol. 4. New York: WH Freeman, 2000.

Alberts, Bruce, et al. "Molecular biology of the cell." Garland Science, New York 4 (2002)(the first few editions had James Watson himself as the editor)

Brown, Terence A. Genomes. Garland science, 2006.

For basics. I would recommend staring with Brown, and going on to Bruce Alberts and then Lodish. That's the way I learnt it.

For a really nice book with pictures (yes, we all like those) you might want to look into Lippincotts illustrated reviews (biochemistry, cell and molecular biology and the like). They are also quite good.

For a specific emphasis on techniques, I'd  recommend this:

Sambrook, Joseph, Edward F. Fritsch, and Tom Maniatis. Molecular cloning. Vol. 1. No. 7.58. New York: Cold spring harbor laboratory press, 1989.
(You can read the contents here http://www.molecularcloning.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am actually a PhD. So I need to refresh my knowledge and get update with more recent molecular/genetic techniques

Comment: @efrem Updated my answer with a bookset on cloning.

Answer (score 2):

If it's techniques you are interested in, [Weaver](http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/0073525324/information_center_view0/index.html), now in its 5th edition, has (had) a strong emphasis on recent experiments from the literature, and he is constantly updating the book. We used  to use it for a variety of courses.

Answer (score 2):

[Brock's Microbiology](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/Brock-Biology-of-Microorganisms-14E/9780321897398.page) is a great book when you are interested in unicellular organisms.

From the publishers's website ([Pearson](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/Brock-Biology-of-Microorganisms-14E/9780321897398.page)):

> The authoritative #1 textbook for introductory majors **microbiology**, Brock Biology of Microorganisms continues to set the standard [...]. This book for biology, microbiology, and other science majors balances cutting edge research with the concepts essential for understanding the field of microbiology, including strong coverage of ecology, evolution, and metabolism. The Fourteenth Edition [...] pay[s] particular attention to **molecular biology** and how the genomic revolution has changed and is changing the field.